# Azure PowerShell Set-AzureService/Get-AzureService -error: the hosted service does not exist

Tags: powershell, azure, reverse-dns

I've just installed the latest Azure PowerShell 1.1 and I am following this blog entry to add reverse DNS to an existing Linux VM that I am running:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/

When I try to run the `Set-AzureService` or `Get-AzureService` commands,

eg. `Get-AzureService "vmname"`

or

`Set-AzureService –ServiceName “vmname” –Description “VM with Reverse DNS” –ReverseDnsFqdn “vmname.cloudapp.net.”`

where my VM is at vmname.cloudapp.net, I get an error like:

> "Get-AzureService : ResourceNotFound: The hosted service does not
>   exist."

But I know my VM is there - if I run `Get-AzureRmResource` I see:

> Name              : portalXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ResourceId        :
>   /subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/Default-Storage-WestUS/providers
>                       /Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/portalXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>   ResourceName      : portalXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ResourceType      :
>   Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts ResourceGroupName :
>   Default-Storage-WestUS Location          : westus SubscriptionId    :
>   XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
>
> Name              : vmname ResourceId        :
>   /subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/vmname/providers/Microsoft.Classi
>                       cCompute/domainNames/vmname ResourceName      : vmname ResourceType      : Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames
>   ResourceGroupName : vmname Location          : westus SubscriptionId
>   : XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
>
> Name              : vmname ResourceId        :
>   /subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/vmname/providers/Microsoft.Classi
>                       cCompute/virtualMachines/vmname ResourceName      : vmname ResourceType      : Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines
>   ResourceGroupName : vmname Location          : westus SubscriptionId
>   : XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

I'm guessing something has changed since that documentation came out. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Solved - looks like my VM was associated with my Visual Studio Premium account, but I had set my default subscription to Visual Studio Enterprise. After switching the default subscription, the Get/Set-AzureService commands worked perfectly.

For additional details, see my other related question

[Azure powershell Select-AzureSubscription - error: the subscription name doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961993/azure-powershell-select-azuresubscription-error-the-subscription-name-doesnt)