# Is there a way to get the key for Classic Azure Storage Account using powershell?

Tags: azure-storage

I think Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey doesn't work with Classic Azure Storage Account. Get-AzureStorageAccount can return classic storage account, but it won't return the key.

thanks.
Lidong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cmdlet : Get-AzureStorageKey

```
Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName "ContosoStore01"
```

Comment: According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34963304/669692
For classic resources you need to precede it with 
Add-AzureAccount and Select-AzureSubscription